# Pasting Alignment issue Photoshop and Illustrator CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, cs4, import

I'm trying to copy layers from Photoshop CS4 to Illustrator CS4, but when I paste each layer from Photoshop to Illustrator all my layers are centered instead of staying in the position they were in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Copying a selection from Photoshop and pasting in to Illustrator will only paste to the bounds of the contents you selected (i.e. the same selection as if you <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the layer, not the entire bounds of the canvas) and won't remember any positioning of those selections.

You can however just open or place a PSD in Illustrator and your layers will be intact, positioned and arranged correctly. Simply open or place the PSD (make sure to uncheck "link" if you are placing) and make sure you select "Convert Layers to Objects" in the Photoshop Import Options window.

Comment: Thank you Cai!  Could you you point me in the direction to help with taking an image with a gradient and vectoring it so I can do separations for a shirt, please?

Comment: That may not be a simple question and depends on a lot of things... probably worth asking a new question with as much detail as possible on the printing methods etc.